# Cron job failing with error code 302

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I am trying to create a cron job in GAE using java but it is failing with below error message.

```
2013-07-22 18:46:13.336 /cron/addCount/1 302 184ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
0.1.0.1 - - [22/Jul/2013:18:46:13 -0700] "GET /cron/addCount/1 HTTP/1.1" 302 148 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "nfactsocial.appspot.com" ms=184 cpu_ms=86 cpm_usd=0.000017 queue_name=__cron task_name=00bb386ed1578e2c78a432e9debd4ca2 app_engine_release=1.8.2 instance=00c61b117c969fb7897a43da0d38d5b3b68029
```

Below is my cron.xml file :

```
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/cron/addCount/1</url>
    <description>Add count + 1 every 1 minutes</description>
    <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

I haven't use any admin related securities but still it is failing. Can anyone please help ?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any more error text?  The log shows the HTTP status code 302 which means the hit is being redirected.  It appears to be redirecting the cron script to the login page at "/".

Comment: No, this is the only log being shown in the logs. I have tried hitting the url directly and it's working fine but hitting with cron job is not working.

Comment: Is it possible that you are logged in (by means of the cookies on your own computer) ?  What happens if you clear the cookies on your machine and try hitting that URL?

Comment: Still the same issue. I an using below method but it seems to be having problem in redirection :

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cronTotal.do" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public void getCount(ModelMap model) {
 
  model.addAttribute("total", 1);
  System.out.println("s");
  return;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have any filter active for the root, so the first the app is doing is trying to validate this filter. I had the same problema as you, and finally it was the filter applied to root who was redirecting me before the cron action.